# Custom sign in controller undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm getting an error I can't seem to solve in my controller. I'm trying to log users in to a blog.

The error is a NoMethodError in BlogSessions#create: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

My controller:

```
class BlogSessionsController < ApplicationController
 def new
    if signed_in?
        sign_out
        redirect_to '/blogs'
    end
end

def create
    blogger = Blogger.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if blogger && blogger.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        blog_sign_in blogger
        flash.now[:success] = "Aaaaand we're back!"
      redirect_to "/blogs"
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      redirect_to '/blog/sign_in'
    end
end

def destroy
    sign_out
    flash[:success] = "See you again soon!"
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

end

Session helper:

```
module BlogSessionsHelper
def blog_sign_in(blogger)
    session[:blogger_email] = blogger.email
end
```

end

Not sure if these are helpful too, but here's the model:

```
class Blogger < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password

before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: true
validates :password, length: { minimum: 5 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
def Blogger.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

def Blogger.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)   end

  private

def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = Blogger.digest(Blogger.new_remember_token)
end
```

end

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Adding sign in view:

```
<div id="blog">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
            <h1>Log in</h1>
            <%= form_for(:blog_session, url: blog_signin_path) do |f| %>
              <%= f.label :email %>  
              <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control form", placeholder: "Email" %>

              <%= f.label :password %>
              <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control form", placeholder: "Password" %>

              <div class="button-container">
                <a href="/blogs" class="cancel button">Cancel</a>
                <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "save button" %>
              </div>
           <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the sign-in form as well?

Comment: It looks like you have a case where you're trying to call `[]` on a nil object. Could it be that `params[:session]` is nil? Can you post what your params are and what line the error is pointing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that due to the naming of the `form_for` in the view, the parameters that are passed in are namespaced under the `blog_session` key, rather than `session`.  To accommodate this, change the references in the controller#create method.

```
def create
  blogger = Blogger.find_by(email: params[:blog_session][:email].downcase)
  if blogger && blogger.authenticate(params[:blog_session][:password])
    blog_sign_in blogger
    flash.now[:success] = "Aaaaand we're back!"
    redirect_to "/blogs"
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    redirect_to '/blog/sign_in'
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thanks a lot.